# show blog Author , title , label and time in a specific div blogger

Tags: tags, label, title, blogger, author

---

For SEO purposes I wanted to copy this blog post design [this website](http://www.th3professional.com/2016/10/blog-post_14.html)
the specific part I want to copy is the div with id="enter-posts" which has the title, the author, date, labels of the post

I tried to put tags like:

`<div class='author-profile' itemprop='author' itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='http://schema.org/Person'>
<meta expr:content='data:post.authorProfileUrl' itemprop='url'/>
<b:if cond='data:post.authorPhoto.url'><a expr:href='data:post.authorProfileUrl' itemprop='url'>
<div class='auhtor-image'><img expr:src='data:post.authorPhoto.url' itemprop='image'/></div></a></b:if>
<div><span class='author-about'>About </span><a class='g-profile' expr:href='data:post.authorProfileUrl' rel='author' title='author profile'><span itemprop='name'><data:post.author/></span></a></div><p class='description' itemprop='description'><data:post.authorAboutMe/></p></div>`

for author and so on for the other elements I want to add but the problem is:

Nothing is displayed, **BUT** when I put these tags inside the post body before the title or at the end of the post they appear normally. what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Though this is an old post, may I post some clarification for those looking for an answer. Fact is, there is no `data:post.authorPhoto.url` provided by blogger.

Most template writers take the data from `/feeds/posts/default` and parse the JSON and update the HTML after page load. Then they obfuscate the js code, making new comers think it was all fetched from blogger. Along with that fetch, who knows what else was fetched.

For example, for the above blog, you can fetch the JSON from http://www.th3professional.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script

My implementation

1. Image is fetched directly from the feed
2. Author description is fetched from 'Introduction' part of user profile. Since that's CORS, I'm using a CORS proxy (https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/) for that purpose.

-

```
var HttpClient = function() {
 this.get = function(aUrl, aCallback) {
    var anHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    anHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (anHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && anHttpRequest.status == 200)
            aCallback(anHttpRequest.responseText);
    }

    anHttpRequest.open("GET", "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/"+aUrl, true);            
    anHttpRequest.send(null);
}
}

$(document).ready(function($){
// This is one way to get post id, other ways are possible too
var post_id = $("div[itemprop='articleBody']").attr('id');
 post_id = post_id.match(/.*post-body-(\d+).*/);
 post_id = ((post_id!==null && post_id.length>0) ? post_id[1] : null);

 if(post_id!==null) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/feeds/posts/default/"+post_id+"?alt=json-in-script",
        type: 'get',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data) {
            var image = ((data.entry.author[0]["gd$image"].src!==null) ? data.entry.author[0]["gd$image"].src : false);

            if(image!=false) { //site correct class here
                $('.author-image').attr('src', image);
            }

            var description = false;
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.get((data.entry.author[0].uri["$t"]).replace("http", "https"), function(response) {
                 var doc = document.documentElement.cloneNode();
                 doc.innerHTML = response;
                 $content = $(doc.querySelectorAll('tr'));
                 for(var lk=0; lk<$content.find('th.item-key').length; lk++) {
                    if($content.find('th.item-key')[lk].innerText=="Introduction" && $content[lk].querySelectorAll('td')[0]!==null) {
                        description = $content[lk].querySelectorAll('td')[0].textContent;
                        break;
                    }
                 }

                 if(description!=false) { //site correct class here
                    $('.description').text(description);
                 }
            });
        }
    }); } });
```